# Finding discontinuity in a function with constants.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Question - need to find discontinuity points for the following function for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> \dfrac{x^{2}+\alpha x+\beta}{x^{2}-8x+15} && x\neq3,5\\[1ex]
> 0 && x=3,5
> \end{cases}$$

I am having trouble arranging myself as I dont know if I should split this into few cases ? if yes what exact cases ? I know to prove all of the limits that can appear here but these constants caught me off guard.

I did the first case is when $ \alpha=\beta=0 $

But from there on  - no idea. 
Will appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible points of discontinuity are $3$ and $5$. Now, for which $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do you have discontinuity at these points?

So notice that:

- $f$ is continuous at $3$ iff $\lim_{x\to 3} f(x)=0$, iff $x^2+\alpha x+\beta =(x-3)^2$, cause in such a case
  \begin{align*}
  \lim_{x\to 3}\frac{x^2+\alpha x +\beta}{x^2-8x+15}&=\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{(x-3)^2}{(x-3)(x-5)}\\[3pt]
  &=\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x-3}{x-5}\\[3pt]
  &= 0
  \end{align*}
- $f$ is continuous at $5$ iff $\lim_{x\to 5} f(x)=0$, iff $x^2+\alpha x+\beta =(x-5)^2$, cause in such a case
  \begin{align*}
  \lim_{x\to 5}\frac{x^2+\alpha x +\beta}{x^2-8x+15}&=\lim_{x\to 5}\frac{(x-5)^2}{(x-3)(x-5)}\\[3pt]
  &=\lim_{x\to 5} \frac{x-5}{x-3}\\[3pt]
  &= 0
  \end{align*}

Therefore, we conclude the folowing: $f$ is discontinuous

- Only at $3$ if $\alpha = -10$ and $\beta = 25$
- Only at $5$ if $\alpha = -6$ and $\beta = 9$
- In both points $3$ and $5$ if $(-10,25)\neq (\alpha, \beta) \neq (-6, 9)$.